# Error connecting to database in mysql using "mysqli", Where am I wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a User registration page, in which a user submits credentials and it stores to database. Next task is supplying user an activation-cum-verification link to users mail inbox, such a way that user clicks the link and the activation code pertaining to user must update to NULL and makes his account active, so that he can log in.

My code :
FILE 1 : mysite.php

```
if($_REQUEST['Itemid']==209)
      {
            $email_id=$_REQUEST['email'];
            if($email_id != '')
            {


//This if condition will submit the data into the database

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
HTML_mysite::newuser($subdom_names, $section_ord, $status); 
} 

else {

//$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

$hostname = 'localhost'; //the parameters for the club database
$sqluser  = 'root';
$sqlpass  = '';
$dbName   = 'club';

// Get connection to MySQL
$link = @mysql_pconnect($hostname, $sqluser, $sqlpass) or die('Unable to connect to database');
// Select the database
@mysql_select_db($dbName) or die('Unable to select database');

//check if the email id already exists.

$query_usrchk = "SELECT EML, PSW FROM visitor WHERE EML = '$_POST[email]'";

//Data is being inserted in visitor table


$result_usrchk = mysql_query($query_usrchk);
$num_rows_usrchk = mysql_num_rows($result_usrchk);

//update  if email/password if correct


if($num_rows_usrchk == 1) // Checking if email id is present in the database..,if yes, status will be displayed.
{

$status="This Email address is already registered with us";
             HTML_mysite::newuser($subdom_names, $section_ord, $status);

}
else

{
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

$query_usrinsert = "INSERT INTO visitor(`confirm_code`,`EML`, `PSW`, `PFN`, `FFN`, `GD1`, `AID`, `FA1`, `FP1`, `CT1`, `CN1`, `FT1`, `MOB`, `CID`)
VALUES ('$confirm_code','$_POST[email]','$_POST[pswd]', '$_POST[name]',  '$_POST[organisation]',  '$_POST[department]',  '$_POST[designation]',  '$_POST[address]',  '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[zipcode]', '$_POST[country]', '$_POST[phonenumber]', '$_POST[mobile]', '$_POST[special]')";


     $result_usrinsert = mysql_query($query_usrinsert);
}

}
```

FILE 2:confirm.php

```
<?
include('config1.php');

$passkey=$_GET['passkey'];


if(isset($passkey)){
$query_activate_account = "UPDATE visitor SET confirm_code=NULL WHERE(EML ='$email' AND confirm_code='$passkey')LIMIT 1";
$result_activate_account = mysqli_query($link,$query_activate_account);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) == 1) //if update query was successfull
{
echo "Your account is now active. You may now login here : http://*********/club/login/login.php";
}
else
echo "Not activated";
}

?>
```

FILE 3: config1.php

```
<?php
$hostname='localhost';
$sqluser='root';
$sqlpass='';
$dbName='club';
$link=@mysqli_connect($hostname,$sqluser,$sqlpass) or die('Error Connecting');
@mysqli_select_db($dbName,$link) or die('Unable to connect');
?>
```

My output when clicked on the link is Unable to connect!!

Please help me.

Comment: You "are wrong" at `@mysqli_select_db($dbName,$link) or die('Unable to connect');`.

Comment: You seem to be mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions?

Comment: Don't put `@` in front of functions. It suppresses warnings so you're basically telling PHP not to help you diagnose the problem

Comment: @N.B. Oh well, may be thanks, but can you tell me the right way>? , you mean not to insert mysqli ?

Comment: Thanks Juhana and Pekka - is it a blunder to mix mysql and mysqli ??

Comment: @highlander141 - if `mysqli_select_db` fails for some reason, it generates an error that tells you what caused it to fail. Instead of echoing that error, you chose to die with the message 'Unable to connect'. 99% is that your $dbName contains name of the database that doesn't exist.

Comment: Fix that SQL-injection: `$query_usrchk = "SELECT EML, PSW FROM visitor WHERE EML = '$_POST[email]'";` -> `$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); $query_usrchk = "SELECT EML, PSW FROM visitor WHERE EML = 'email' ";` And stop storing **unencrypted** passwords (PSW) in your database.

Comment: The problem with this question is: 1. 90% of the code is irrelevant. You're trying to solve the reason why you can't connect to your database so we only need to see that code. 2. You don't specify which block of code you get the `Unable to connect` message raised (there's two possibilities) 3. You're hiding essential error information by choosing to `die()` and suppressing warnings. Please go back and try a simple script to connect and execute a query without the `@` and `die()` statement, tell us what error you get then flag to re-open.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems in your code.

1. you are mixing 2 APIs - mysql and mysqli ones. Although you can use both at the same time, your code have to be consistent and use corresponding methods without mixing them. once connected via mysqli you have to use mysqli_* function to use this connection and so forth.
2. you are **gagging** an error message that might explain what's wrong with your database.

remove all **@** symbols from your code and run it again.
you will see a sensible error message telling you what is wrong.